# Get each post id with all comments using facebook FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

i want to get each post id with all comments for a page using fql query.if i use  -

```
SELECT text,post_id  FROM comment  WHERE post_id IN(SELECT post_id  FROM stream  WHERE source_id=page_id_here)
```

this returns -

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "text": "Would be nice if my website would let me do the update. It says I have the most current version 2.5.9 :(",
      "post_id": "2211155996_10151336546425997"
    },
    {
      "text": "All of mine just started showing the update message in the last hour and just got the emails from Admin tools.",
      "post_id": "2211155996_10151336546425997"
    },
........continues
```

as you see it returns text and post_id in one object.what i want is there will be post_id and its all comments in one object.hope i get answer as i am struggling for a hour.It's something to do with multi queries with join

Comment: i thought here i will get reply soon than other site..but where is experts?

Comment: look like nobody want to waste time anymore with FB stuffs..